# VLAN Creation no Internet Access

Tags: gateway, vlan

I have a dell switch 6200.

I am trying to add a new VLAN to the current VLANs.
I currently have a VLAN that is 192.168.01 255.255.255.0.
The default Gateway is 192.168.0.1.

I created a VLAN 192.168.5.1 but I cannot get access to the internet.
I don't understand why 192.168.0.1 is the default gateway for the other VLAN.

How would add a Default Gateway to 192.168.5.1 to allow me to get internet access?

Comment: What device currently owns 192.168.0.1, your Dell switch, or your firewall/router?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a gateway on the vlan 192.168.5.0/24 too. Without it, there is no way a device can connect to another vlan.

Depending on what you use as a router, it might be possible to configure the port towards it as a trunk, and configure your router to be on two vlans at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace VLAN with network and read this: [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Summarised:

You have a network 192.168.0/24. All traffic on for that network gets sent to it. All traffic with a different destination get send via the gateway 192.168.0.1, which is on the 192.168.0/24 network and thus is directly reachable.

Now you add a second network. 192.168.5/24. All traffic for that specific network can be sent to it. All traffic with a different destination needs a gateway **which is directly reachable** from 192.168.5/24. That does not include 192.168.0.1.

> How would adding a default gateway to 192.168.5.1 to allow me to get internet access?

It would not. You will need a NIC in the local network (192.168.5/24) which can forward packets to and from other networks. Assuming that everywhere you wrote VLAN you meant 'network' or 'LAN' then you can do this by adding a second IP and appropriate routing tables to the host which currently serves as the gateway for the 192.168.0/24 network.

However as your question currently stands that requires some guessing. You will either need to clarify it or learn how subnetting and routing works.